# Remove last character on each line

Tags: php, replace, substr

I have made a script which reads all CSV files from a folder, puts the data to my database and moves all the csv file to another folder afterward.

I get emails with tables which are meant to put it into a CSV file, I am trying to create a script which reads my mail, only shows the emails with tables and converts the text into a CSV file, moves the file to my folder, reads it and transfers the data. The biggest part is done already, but I am struggling with this bit.

After filtering the mail and having the table, I took away the HTML tags `(<table>, <p>, <tr> etc.)` I am replacing the `</td>` with tabs because it has to separate the rows, but on the last `</td>` it also adds a tab and that makes my script unable to read the CSV files because the separator are tabs and on the last tab there is no value given.

This is my HTML table after removing all the tags with string and preg replace, and as you see, it has a tab on the end (Sorry for hiding some text)

[image: HTML Table]

I have tried some rtrims and substr, but I haven't been able to be doing this for each line.

`echo substr($key, 0, -1);` Only takes away the tab on the last line, it is 1 full string so I am not sure if it is possible.

If any more code is needed then I'd like to hear it.
Sorry for the long question, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks =)

Comment: Please, dont' use the screenshot for the code or the messages, but always put the source code in the post with the appropriate command of the editor. Thank you

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I tried to keep my question as short as possible, pasting the code would make my question look bigger.

Comment: I just noticed that I could try to replace all <td> with a tab but every 8th <td> I can replace it into nothing, so 8th <td> will be "" 16th <td> will be "" etc.

Comment: Loop every line and apply `trim`

Comment: Could you use comma instead of tab ?

Comment: I can't use a comma instead of tab, sorry

Comment: I have tried looping through it with a foreach, but it didn't work x(

Comment: You can split lines with `$lines = preg_split('@\R@', $subject);` if needed and then use a foreach and trim, or do something like: `join("\n", array_map('trim', preg_split('@\R@', $subject)));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question.
I am replacing all my `<td>` with tabs, and every 8th tab gets replaced with nothing, so I'm removing it.

This is the code that I've used:

```
$res_str = array_chunk(explode("\t",$outputstr),8);
foreach( $res_str as &$val){
   $val  = implode("\t",$val);
}
echo implode("",$res_str);
```

I'm so happy actually, took me so long to first even analyze the problem for not being able to read the CSV file and then fixing it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, did you try my suggestions?

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work, I really do appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) functions with \t\n characters:

```
str_replace("\t\n","\n", $string);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I don't know how this will help.

Comment: I think that I know what you mean, when there is a tab and a new line, it will 'remove' the tab, nice idea, but it didn't work, you have to use double quotes for this and not single btw x)

Comment: \t means tab and \n means new line. so when you have passed your string to ' str_replace ' function it's find any last tab in each line and replaces it just with new line character. so the new tab at end of the lines removed automatically.

Comment: Yes, I have commented that already, such an original idea, thanks a lot, but it didn't work x(

Comment: It didn't work with double quotations ;( echo str_replace("\t\n","\n", $outputstr);

Comment: @ShockingShell what are your line endings?

Comment: Ends with a tab (/x0D) and starts with a new line (/x0A) (0D is a tab and 0A is a new line)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the m (PCRE_MULTILINE) modifier in a regex.

This should strip trailing space from every line of your string (below $subject).  If you didn't use the m modifier, it would only remove the trailing space at the end of the string.

```
<?php

$pattern = "@\s$@m";
$subject = "'a'\t'b'\t'c'\t\n'd'\t'e'\t'f'\t\n";

$out     = preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject);
print $out;
```

Output:

```
'a' 'b' 'c'
'd' 'e' 'f'
```

Do try it on your subject as the output is hard to read here.

Comment: I don't want to make you feel bad, but I honestly don't know how this works, trying to gain more knowledge of it from php.net

Comment: @ShockingShell, I've added a small explanation, it's just a multi-find and replace, that should strip trailing space including tabs from the end of each line.